# mitmproxy standalone script?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am trying to convert a python script which works perfectly with mitmdump (*mitmdump -q -s script.py*) to a standalone script.

My current script looks like this:

```
def request(flow):
   ...

def response(flow):
   ...
```

I have found [examples](http://2qwesgdhjuiytyrjhtgdbf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting/mitmproxy.html) which are subclassing FlowMaster, however the [documentation](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2954) states that this is not the preferred method and to rather use inline scripts.
What would be the current way to create a standalone script using mitmproxy?